# JavaScript context: Access Vuejs data inside Rapheljs drag callable function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, raphael

I understand it is not specifically Vuejs or Rapheljs issue but the way `this` is bound to a context. Generally we can pass parent context by using arrow function or using `bind`.

But it this case I want to access both the context i.e.

1. `this` of `drag` refers to dragged svg element which I need
2. I also need Vuejs data to update which we usually access using `this`

Code:

```
circle.drag(circdragmove, circdragstart, circdragend);

function cirdragmove(dx, dy, x, y, e){
          let ox = this.data("ox");
          let oy = this.data("oy");
          if(ox + dx > 0){
            this.attr("cx", parseInt(this.data("ox")) + dx);
          }
          if(oy + dy > 0){
            this.attr("cy", parseInt(this.data("oy")) + dy);
          }
        }
```

Inside `circdragmove`, `this` refers to circle svg element. In this function I want to update some Vuejs data. How to go about it?

Comment: Keep Raphael js code out of Vue component. Call it from one of the Vue component methods and return the result to be updated in the component.

Comment: Why don't you bind rapheljs like you mentioned using `bind` and backup your vue's `this` context by saving it in a variable like `const self = this`? This way you'll be able to access vue inside that function using `self`.

Comment: @PhilipFeldmann I returned to write this solution only! For future reference, this solution works.

Comment: @TusharArora Can you please elaborate on this. Why should we keep both separate?